# django how to display the details page for a newly added product

Tags: python, django

I am still a learner for python django. I am trying to create a site where user can Add the a new product and should be able to see the details of the latest added product in another page. I am able to achieve the first part i.e the Add Product page. But i need help as to how to get the detail page correct. Request the guidance.

My model.py is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CASCADE
from django.urls import reverse

from category.models import Subcategory, Category
from category.utils import unique_slugify

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, related_name='products', on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        slug_str = "%s %s %s" % (self.name, self.category, self.subcategory)
        unique_slugify(self, slug_str)
        super(Product, self).save(**kwargs)
```

My views.py looks as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, ListView

from category.models import Subcategory
from product.forms import ProductForm
from product.models import Product



class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'

class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_changelist')

def productlist(request):
    prodlist = Product.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
    return render(request, 'product/product_list.html', {'prodlist': prodlist})

class ProductUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product_changelist')

def load_subcategory(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategory = Subcategory.objects.filter(category_id=category_id).order_by('name')
return render(request, 'product/subcategory_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subcategory': subcategory})
```

My urls.py for product app looks as follows:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
    path('add/', views.ProductCreateView.as_view(), name='product_add'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product_change'),
    path('ajax/load-subcategory/', views.load_subcategory, name='ajax_load_subcategory'),

]
```

The main urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from category.views import CategoryListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('category/', CategoryListView.as_view()),
    path('category/', include('category.urls')),
    path('product/', include('product.urls'), name='product'),
]
```

I have created a product_list.html in which i want to show the latest added product details.

it just have this code:

```
{{ prodlist }}
```

Currently on adding a new product, i can see product in the localhost:8000/admin page. 
But after clicking on the Add button, i see a blank page localhost:8000/product

Thanks in advance for all the help and guidance

Answer (score 0):

If the page is completely blank, that may mean your query is not actually returning anything in your view. You could try printing your prodlist from the view and check your console to see if anything is returned.

A better strategy might be to have a unique show page for every product.

Instead of taking all products and grabbing the newest one, having a page for any product. This would allow more flexibility and allow you to see any product easily.

Your new urls.py for your app could looks something like

```
 urlpatterns = [
  path('<product_id>', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_changelist'),
  path('add/', views.ProductCreateView.as_view(), name='product_add'),
  path('<int:pk>/', views.ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product_change'),
  path('ajax/load-subcategory/', views.load_subcategory, name='ajax_load_subcategory'),
]
```

Then in your views.py

```
def productlist(request, product_id):
  product = Product.objects.get(productid=product_id)
  return render(request, 'product/product_list.html', {'product': product})
```

Then finally in your store list:

```
{{product.name}}
```

Unfortunately without more info its hard to pin down your error, I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for suggesting... I tried your suggestion and i get the following when i am in localhost:8000/product/add/ page
       NoReverseMatch at /product/add/
       Reverse for 'product_changelist' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:['product\\/(?P<product_id>[^/]+)$']

Comment: Before trying your suggestion, i tried entering some text in that product_list.html, that text is displayed. That means with my code, i was able to go to that page, but was not getting what i was expecting...that is, the details about the product just being added.